# How to receive feedback from server

Tags: android, client, chat

When an update is happening on the server side for a specific user then the server will notify
to that user by pushing a notification.

Let two client A and B are friend. Both have registered to the server. Both have a message field in the database for storing message receiving from others.

B has sent a message to A's message field. Now server's task is to check A's message field. 
If there is a recent message for A, then the server will notify A by sending this message.
How can i solve this. Any suggestion will appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

Google has a push notification system for android called [C2DM](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/android/c2dm/)

Keep in mind this system is merely designed to sign A that there is a new message, not to actually push the complete message to the device. After receiving the notification the device should contact the server to fetch the message.